# show hide button depending on time in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-paper

How to hide the button for 5s in ember.js

This is my template activation.hbs

```
{{#if hideResendCode}}
  {{#paper-button raised=true primary=true}}Resend Code{{/paper-button}}
{{/if}}
```

and this is my controller activation.js

```
hideResendCode:Ember.run.later((function() {

 }), 5000),
```

I don't know how to hide this button for 5s please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run scheduler in `init`.

```
{{#if showResendCode}}
  {{#paper-button raised=true primary=true}}Resend Code{{/paper-button}}
{{/if}}
```

And

```
    //activation.js
    showResendCode: true,

init(){
  this._super(...arguments);
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
          this.set('showResendCode', false);
        }, 5000);
}
```